# What is the lifetime of the deuteron with respect to sphaleron-induced decay

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, electroweak, instantons, half-life

As far as I've understood, instantons like the sphaleron can give rise to processes that violate $B+L$ but conserve $B-L$, where the baryon and lepton number can only change by a multiple of three. That would imply the deuteron could decay in an antiproton and a few triplets of leptons.

I'm curious what the lifetime of the deuteron would be with respect to this process. I would be satisfied with a very rough estimate; I understand it's going to be an immense number.